# F# implicit cast operator ReadOnlySpan<char> conflict

Tags: .net-core, f#

I have defined the following implicit cast operator:

`let inline (!>) (x:^a) : ^b = ((^a or ^b) : (static member op_Implicit : ^a -> ^b) x)`

This allows me to use a json library like so:

```
    root.[objTypeKey] <- !> o.Desc.ObjType
```

Where root is a JSONNode, and it's indexer expects another JSONNodeas value. ObjType is a string, and there is a simple implicit cast operator definition in the json library (written in C#) from string to JSONNode.

This entire thing worked quite nicely on .Net Framework, but migrating the F# project to .Net Core 3.1 (the C# json lib is on .Net Standard 2.0) there is a new conflict, with the new implicit cast operator of string -> `ReadOnlySpan<char>`

Can this be circumvented somehow, while still leaving the original `!>` operator usage? and if yes, how? Can I somehow disallow `ReadOnlySpan<char>` from interfering (it's unneeded in this project).

The specific compiler error:

```
Error   FS0041  No overloads match for method 'Item'.

Known types of arguments: string * ReadOnlySpan<char>

Available overloads:
 - JSONNode.set_Item(aIndex: int, value: JSONNode) : unit // Argument 'aIndex' doesn't match
 - JSONNode.set_Item(aKey: string, value: JSONNode) : unit // Argument 'value' doesn't match
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one idea. You can declare a second, non-generic version of `!>` that's specific to `JSONNode`:

```
module JSONNode =
    let (!>) = JSONNode.op_Implicit
```

The F# compiler will prefer that version when the module is open. The only problem is that it will prevent usage of the generic version.

Usage:

```
module Example1 =
    let node = JSONNode()
    node.["key"] <- !> "value"   // Error: ReadOnlySpan<char>

module Example2 =
    open JSONNode
    let node = JSONNode()
    node.["key"] <- !> "value"   // Success: JSONNode
```